# React Check prevState in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am moving to React Hooks functional component

I am refactoring the code below with an `useEffect`

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { visible } = this.props;
    if (prevProps.visible === visible) { return; }
  }
```

In my case i want to check the `prevState` of my selector `visible`

I am using this Hook `usePrevious`

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); 
  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
}
```

So my way to access to the previous state with Hooks is

```
const visible = useSelector((state) => state.visible);
const [flagVisible, setFlagVisible] = useState(visible);
const preVisible = usePrevious(flagVisible);

useEffect(() => {
  if (preVisible === visible) {
    return;
  }
},[])
```

I do not understand why i get `preVisible` undefined with this hook. What am i doing wrong? How can i access to the prevState of visible and check that is not equal to my actual state in the `useEffect`?

Comment: What is the original `componentDidUpdate()` even doing? Is there other code beneath that `if()` condition that isn't being run if it returns early? Otherwise that code doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Yes i want to do the same, if the prev  state of visible is same as visible i dont want to run the uSeffect

Comment: I agree with romellem here, it doesn't appear as though the `componentDidUpdate` is doing anything, so it's unclear what or why you need to even create something in a React Function component via the `useEffect` that equally does nothing. You could just as well write `useEffect(() => {})`, or omit it entirely, and accomplish the same thing with less work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check if the last value was different. The dependencies array is how you tell React when to run the callback:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // `visible` was changed
}, [visible]);
```

The callback will not run if none of the given dependencies changed.